# SumIf (conditional Sum) in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, aggregate-functions

I have two models: Publisher and Book.

I am retrieving publishers with

```
Publisher.objects.filter(name="A").annotate(total_pages=Sum('books__num_pages'))
```

but I am only interested in the total sum of number of pages for books written in 2014.

I am not familiar with any options to make a SUMIF in Django. How does others solve this problem?

I think there should be some possibility to do something like

```
Sum('books__num_pages', where={'year': 2014})
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

You were very close to actual proper solution (or maybe django didn't have it back in 2014?), [`Sum` function has a `filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#sum) parameter, so you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q
...
Publisher.objects.filter(name="A").annotate(total_pages=Sum('books__num_pages', filter=Q(year=2014)))
```

Comment: I think this solution is slightly incorrect the filter should be in the Sum() ie Publisher.objects.filter(name="A").annotate(total_pages=Sum('books__num_pages', filter=Q(year=2014)))

Comment: @ScottWarren of course, a typo, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
books_num_pages = Books.objects.filter(publisher__name='A', year=2014).aggregate(Sum('num_pages'))
```

Comment: Now I wont get those publishers with no related books.

Comment: `Publisher.objects.filter(books__isnull=True)`

Comment: Now I wont get the annotation

Comment: Now you want read the docs ;) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude. But I don't think you understood what I mean. It seems there is a still running ticket for my problem at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11305 and a temporary solution at https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-aggregate-if/blob/master/aggregate_if.py

Comment: if you have complicated query you can always use `extra` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra or even db.cursor for that, or change default orm to sql alchemy